# htaccess entries are being interpreted as requests

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, php-7.1

I have the following htaccess entries

```
php_value post_max_size 109857600
php_value upload_max_filesize 104857600
#php_value post_max_size 200M
#php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value max_execution_time 7200


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(public.?)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(files.?)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(redirect.?)
RewriteRule !(\.(php|htm|html|jnlp|jar|mp3|flv|swf|wma|jpeg|pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|xml|xsl|txt))|public$ index.php


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
Options -Indexes
```

From time to time, on pages that gets many hits per second, those entries are being sent to my index.php (where I use mod rewrite to route all requests to.

I see the following as requests routed to my index.php:

```
post_max_size 
109857600
max_execution_time
7200
```

I am using php 7.1.1 and 
apache 2.2
I am thinking of moving those values into php.ini, which will solve the problem,
but **my worry is this is only a symptom of some other problem I have.**
Any idea how this is caused or how to further debug this?

More info:
I do not see entries for those requests in the apache access logs.
I see them through a log I write to in my index.php

Comment: What does your Apace access.log show?

Comment: I do not see entries for those requests in the access log

Comment: What is frequency of these type of requests (honestly never seen anything like this weird)

Comment: Several times per week, when the same page is being hit a lot (dozens / second)